# How to choose the razor page to handle a request based on a cookie?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages web application with 2 pages; pageA.cshtml and pageB.cshtml.

When visiting the site at a specific URL, I want to choose, for each request, which of these two pages should handle the request based on the value of a cookie.
If the cookie is "A", then use pageA.cshtml and if it is "B", then use pageB.cshtml.

It must not be a redirect.

I have tried to see if a middleware can solve the problem, but I can not find any documentation or examples that show how to choose the razor page that should handle the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could write custom middleware to achieve your requirement.

You could check the cookie in the custom middleware and modify the request path.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }


    app.Use( async (context , next) => {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/page"))
        {
            if (context.Request.Cookies["Page"] != null)
            {
                switch (context.Request.Cookies["Page"])
                {

                    case "A":
                        context.Request.Path = "/pageA";
                        break;
                    case "B":
                        context.Request.Path = "/pageB";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;

                }
            }
        }

        await next();
    } );

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Add cookie page codes:

```
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="AddCookieA">
        <button>AddCookieA</button>
    </form>

    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="AddCookieB">
        <button>AddCookieB</button>
    </form>
```

Code-behind:

```
    public void OnPostAddCookieA() {

        Response.Cookies.Append("Page", "A");
   

    }


    public void OnPostAddCookieB()
    {

        Response.Cookies.Append("Page", "B");


    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Complete code example that just works and even a video showing it in action. How do I upvote this more than once? :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Get() 
{
    if (Request.Cookies["COOKIE_1"] != null) {
        return View("View_Cookie1"); // Consider you have a View_Cookie1.cshtml file
    } else if (Request.Cookies["COOKIE_2"] != null) {
        return View("View_Cookie2"); // returns View_Cookie2.cshtml
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks more like MVC and not like Razor Pages, so that method will not work for me.